# Establish templatetag as django variable

Tags: django, templatetags

I am attempting to filter a django queryset in a template tag, like this:

```
@register.simple_tag
def splice(query, person_id):
    query2 = query.filter(personid=person_id)
    return query2
```

Then, in my template, I would like to pass the newly filtered queryset into an includes html file. Here is my attempt:

```
{% with splice df person_id as x %}
   {% include 'includes/file.html' with df=x %}
```

How can I execute this properly? Or does anyone have ideas how to go about this a more efficient way?

Comment: What happens with this code?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I get an error for the `with` statement: 'with' expected at least one variable assignment

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `with` there; a simple tag can add its data to the context directly with `as`.

```
{% splice df person_id as x %}
```

However, this is probably not the right approach. Instead of writing a template tag to add context for an included template, you should be using an inclusion tag, which takes care of the whole process of including the template with specific context. So:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('template/file.html')
def splice_include(query, person_id):
    query2 = query.filter(personid=person_id)
    return {'df': x}
```

And now you can use it directly:

```
{% splice_include df person_id %}
```

with no need for a separate `include` at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rearrange how you pass the arguments. Using the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#with) provides a nice example. You can then call the templatetag from file.html.

**The calling file**

   `{% include 'includes/file.html' with df=df person_id=person_id %}`

**file.html**

`{% load my_template_tags %}
{{df|slice:person_id}}`